# sum of squares of diagonal binomial coefficients.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients

My question is if there exists a way to evaluate the sum

$$
{{s}\choose{s}}^{\!2} + {{s + 1}\choose{s}}^{\!2} + \ldots {{s+r}\choose{s}}^{\!2}. 
$$

In other words, it's the sum of the squares of the first r binomial coefficients on the s-th right-to-left diagonal of Pascal's triangle. Moreover, is it true that the previous sum is $O_{\!s}(r^{s})$?

Comment: MO copy of the question: [Sum of squares of diagonal binomial coefficients](http://mathoverflow.net/q/266326)

Comment: You might have a look at some [basic info about cross posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info). Especially [this answer on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives a very reasonable advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a nice closed form.

For the second question, perhaps you mean $O(r^{2s+1})$, not $O(r^s)$.  In fact, for each fixed positive integer $s$, ${s+x \choose s}$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $s$, so ${s+x \choose s}^2$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $2s$, and
the partial sum ${s+0 \choose s}^2 + {s+1 \choose s}^2 + \ldots {s+r \choose s}^2$ is a polynomial in $r$ of degree $2s+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Christopher Stocker and I give a combinatorial proof of an identity involving this expression (for $k$th powers, not just squares, but we list the squares as a special case) in our paper ``Two combinatorial proofs of identities involving sums of powers of binomial coefficients'' [Integers 16](http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/vol16.html) (2016) #A58.